# How to ensure two users can atomically confirm transaction has taken place in mongodb

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, transactions, mongodb-query

I have a model called a Transaction which has the following schema

```
var transactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    amount: Number,
    status: String,
    _recipient: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    _sender: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});
```

I want both sender and recipient of this transaction to be able to 'confirm' that the transaction took place. The `status` starts out as "initial". So when only the sender has confirmed the transaction (but the recipient yet not), I want to update the `status` to "senderConfirmed" or something, and when the recipient has confirmed it (but sender has not), I want to update status to "recipientConfirmed". When they have *both* confirmed it, I want to update the status to "complete".

The problem is, how I can know when to update it to "complete" in a way that avoids race conditions? If both sender and recipient go to confirm the transaction at the same time, then both threads will think the status is "initial" and update it just to "senderConfirmed" or "recipientConfirmed", when in actuality it ought to go to "complete".

I read about MongoDBs two phase commit approach [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) but that doesn't quite fit my need, since I don't (in the case that another thread is currently modifying a transaction) want to prevent the second thread from making its update - I just want it to *wait* until the first thread is finished before doing its update, and then making the content of its update contingent on the latest status of the transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bottom line is you need "two" update statement to do this for each of sender and recipient respectively. So basically one is going to try and set the "partial" status to complete, and the other will only set the "initial" status match to the "partial" state.

Bulk operations are the best way to implement multiple statements, so you should use these by accessing the underlying driver methods. Modern API releases have the [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite) method, which degrades nicely if the server version does not support the "bulk" protocol, and just falls back to issuing separate updates.

```js
// sender confirmation
Transaction.collection.bulkWrite(
    [
       { "updateOne": {
           "filter": {
               "_id": docId,
               "_sender": senderId,
               "status": "recipientConfirmed"
           },
           "update": {
               "$set": { "status": "complete" }
           }
       }},
       { "updateOne": {
           "filter": {
               "_id": docId,
               "_sender": senderId,
               "status": "initial"
           },
           "update": {
               "$set": { "status": "senderConfirmed" }
           }
       }}
    ],
    { "ordered": false },
    function(err,result) {
       // result will confirm only 1 update at most succeeded
    }
);
```

And of course the same applies for the `_recipient` except the different status check or change. You could alternately issue an `$or` condition on the `_sender` or `_recipient` and have a generic "partial" status instead of coding different update conditions, but the same basic "two update" process applies.

Of course again you "could" just use the regular methods and issue both updates to the sever in another way, possibly even in parallel since the conditions remain "atomic", but that is also the reason for the `{ "ordered": false }` option since their is no determined sequence that needs to be respected here.

Bulk operations though are better than separate calls, since the send and return is only **one** request and response, as opposed to "two" of each, so the overhead using bulk operations is far less.

But that is the general approach. No single statement could possibly leave a "status" in "deadlock" or mark as "complete" before the other party also issues their confirmation.

There is a "possibility" and a very slim one that a status was changed from "initial" in between the first attempt update and the second, which would result in nothing being updated. In that case, you can "retry" the action on which it "should" update on the subsequent attempt.

This should only ever need "one" retry at most though. And very very rarely.

---

**NOTE**: Care should be taken when using the `.collection` accessor on Mongoose models. All the regular model methods have built in logic to "ensure" the connection to the database is actually present before they do anything, and in fact "queue" operations until a connection is present.

It's generally good practice to wrap your application startup in an event handler to ensure the database connection:

```js
mongoose.on("open",function() {
    // App startup and init here
})
```

So using the `"on"` or `"once"` events for this case.

Generally though a connection is always present either after this event is fired, or after any "regular" model method has already been called in the application.

Possibly mongoose will include methods like `.bulkWrite()` directly on the model methods in future releases. But presently it does not, so the `.collection` accessor is necessary to grab the underlying [Collection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Collection.html) object from the core driver.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I am clarifying my answer based on a comment that my original response did not provide an answer.

An alternative approach would be to keep track of the status as two separate properties:

```
senderConfirmed: true/false,
recipientConfirmed: true/false,
```

When the sender confirms you simply update the `senderConfirmed` field. When the recipient confirms you update the `recipientConfirmed` field. There is no way they will overwrite each other.

To determine if the transaction is complete you would merely query `{senderConfirmed:true,recipientConfirmed:true}`.

Obviously this is a change to the document schema, so it may not be ideal.

**Original Answer**:

Is a change to your schema possible? What if you had two properties - `senderStatus` and `recipientStatus`? Sender would only update `senderStatus` and recipient would only update `recipientStatus`. Then they couldn't overwrite each others changes.

You would still need some other way to mark it as complete, I assume. You could us a cron job or something...